# p:carousel how to keep currentPage after updating form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 6.1 carousel for displaying customer data in multiple pages. 
  Is there a way that backend can reset carousel to a pageindex after updating form or let carousel auto-remember the previous pageindex after form updating? 
  Currently, after updating form, it always goes back to first page.

I checked the carousel.js, might be able to override the methods to do, but before go to that path, just wondering whether there have any other easier/better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Why not only update what needs to be updated and leave the carousel be?

Comment: @kukeltje: do not get ur question. I need to update carousel's content and need to navigate the previous navigated page after updating content.